# Modprobe wl fatal error: module wl not found under /lib/modules/kali-4.6.0-amd64../couldn't get wireless working on BRCM4360 14e4:43a0

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, unix, driver

I have a MacBook Air 2015 11" with Kali GNU/Rolling 64-bit Gnome ver 3.20.2 and Linux kernel: Linux 4.6.0 -kali1-amd64, dual booted side by side with macOS and windows, live mode with persistence and I've been trying to install the wireless drivers for this Mac with a BRCM4360 (14e4:43a0) chip.

What I've done:

Followed instructions on: (EACH ONE OF THEM)

[How to install Broadcom BCM4360 on Debian on MacBook Pro](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175810/how-to-install-broadcom-bcm4360-on-debian-on-macbook-pro)

[Debian/wl](http://wiki.debian.org/wl)

and a lot of other goggles. But couldn't get it solved with either.

It goes easy through :

```
apt-get update    
apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
```

and

```
modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac
```

but whenever i try:

```
modprobe wl
```

terminal returns:

```
root@kali:~# modprobe wl
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.6.0-kali1-amd64
```

Also I'm a newbie to Linux, kernels, networking and modules/drivers and stuff also the only way I could run Kali on this machine was to live boot with persistence as mentioned in PENTESTMAC forums. Actually I could get my wireless driver working about a year earlier just by following all those steps on the forum without any issues (late 2016). But now it doesn't work at the modprobe wl section.

So, any help from scratch would be highly appreciated. It's been weeks. Vigorously SMH.

**edit:**

I even tried this automated script on https://gist.github.com/stevenmirabito/31a6bf9e5bfe4128b0a9

But still the same thing it gave this output:

```
./broadcom-wl-dkms.sh
--2017-07-19 14:11:47--  http://www.broadcm.com/docs/linux_sta/hybrid-v35_64-nodebug-pcoem-6_30_223_271.tar.gz
Resolving www.broadcm.com (www.broadcm.com)... 185.26.230.129
Connecting to www.broadcm.com (www.broadcm.com)|185.26.230.129|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/hybrid-v35_64-nodebug-pcoem-6_30_223_271.tar.gz [following]
--2017-07-19 14:11:49--  http://www.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/hybrid-v35_64-nodebug-pcoem-6_30_223_271.tar.gz
Resolving www.broadcom.com (www.broadcom.com)... 68.142.68.26, 68.142.70.26
Connecting to www.broadcom.com (www.broadcom.com)|68.142.68.26|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://docs.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/hybrid-v35_64-nodebug-pcoem-6_30_223_271.tar.gz [following]
--2017-07-19 14:11:49--  https://docs.broadcom.com/docs/linux_sta/hybrid-v35_64-nodebug-pcoem-6_30_223_271.tar.gz
Resolving docs.broadcom.com (docs.broadcom.com)... 68.142.70.26, 68.142.68.26
Connecting to docs.broadcom.com (docs.broadcom.com)|68.142.70.26|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 102 [text/html]
Saving to: ‘broadcom.tar.gz’

broadcom.tar.gz     100%[===================>]     102  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2017-07-19 14:11:51 (77.3 MB/s) - ‘broadcom.tar.gz’ saved [102/102]

./broadcom-wl-dkms.sh: line 15: https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/snapshot/broadcom-wl-dkms.tar.gz: No such file or directory

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar (child): broadcom-wl-dkms.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
sed: can't read src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c: No such file or directory
./broadcom-wl-dkms.sh: line 23: 001-null-pointer-fix.patch: No such file or directory
sed: can't read dkms.conf.in: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'src': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'lib': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat 'Makefile': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/usr/src/broadcom-wl-6.30.223.271/lib/LICENSE.txt': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/share/licenses/broadcom-wl-dkms/LICENSE': File exists
install: cannot stat 'broadcom-wl-dkms.conf': No such file or directory
dkms.conf: Error! No 'DEST_MODULE_LOCATION' directive specified.
dkms.conf: Error! No 'PACKAGE_NAME' directive specified.
dkms.conf: Error! No 'PACKAGE_VERSION' directive specified.
Error! Bad conf file.
File: /usr/src/broadcom-wl-6.30.223.271/dkms.conf
does not represent a valid dkms.conf file.
rmmod: ERROR: Module b43 is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module b43legacy is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module ssb is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module bcm43xx is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module brcm80211 is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module brcmfmac is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module brcmsmac is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module bcma is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module wl is not currently loaded
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.6.0-kali1-amd64
```

**edit:**
I was however able to remake the script and get those packages downloaded and extracted as this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Installs the broadcom-wl kernel module with DKMS
# Tested under Fedora 23, will likely work with other versions/distros
# Author: Steven Mirabito <smirabito@csh.rit.edu>

# Create a work directory
mkdir -p /tmp/broadcom
cd /tmp/broadcom

# Download the module from Broadcom (http://www.broadcom.com/support/?gid=1)
# Remove '_64' from the URL for a 32-bit system
cp ~/Downloads/hybrid-v35_64-nodebug-pcoem-6_30_223_271.tar.gz /tmp/broadcom/broadcom.tar.gz

# Download some support files from the Arch package
cp -r ~/Downloads/usr /tmp/broadcom/broadcom-wl-dkms

# Untar the archives
tar -zxvf broadcom.tar.gz

# Patch the module
sed -i -e "/BRCM_WLAN_IFNAME/s:eth:wlan:" src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c
patch -p1 < 001-null-pointer-fix.patch

# Add the module version number to the dkms config file
sed -e "s/@PACKAGE_VERSION@/6.30.223.271/" dkms.conf.in > dkms.conf

# Create the destination directory
mkdir -p /usr/src/broadcom-wl-6.30.223.271

# Move files into place
cp -RL src lib Makefile dkms.conf /usr/src/broadcom-wl-6.30.223.271

# Fix permissions and link the license in the appropriate place
chmod a-x "/usr/src/broadcom-wl-6.30.223.271/lib/LICENSE.txt"
mkdir -p "/usr/share/licenses/broadcom-wl-dkms"
ln -rs "/usr/src/broadcom-wl-6.30.223.271/lib/LICENSE.txt" "/usr/share/licenses/broadcom-wl-dkms/LICENSE"

# Install the modprobe config to blacklist the other Broadcom modules
install -D -m 644 broadcom-wl-dkms.conf "/etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-wl-dkms.conf"

# Install and build the module
dkms install -m broadcom-wl -v 6.30.223.271

# Activate the module
rmmod b43 b43legacy ssb bcm43xx brcm80211 brcmfmac brcmsmac bcma wl
modprobe wl

# Clean up
cd ~
rm -rf /tmp/broadcom
```

But still: As soon as I get to the patching it returns this error:

```
root@kali:~/Desktop# sudo ./broadcom-wl-dkms.sh
Makefile
lib/
lib/wlc_hybrid.o_shipped
lib/LICENSE.txt
src/
src/include/
src/include/typedefs.h
src/include/linuxver.h
src/include/bcmutils.h
src/include/siutils.h
src/include/packed_section_start.h
src/include/epivers.h
src/include/linux_osl.h
src/include/bcmendian.h
src/include/packed_section_end.h
src/include/pcicfg.h
src/include/bcmdefs.h
src/include/bcmcrypto/
src/include/bcmcrypto/tkhash.h
src/include/wlioctl.h
src/include/osl.h
src/shared/
src/shared/bcmwifi/
src/shared/bcmwifi/include/
src/shared/bcmwifi/include/bcmwifi_channels.h
src/shared/bcmwifi/include/bcmwifi_rates.h
src/shared/linux_osl.c
src/wl/
src/wl/sys/
src/wl/sys/wl_dbg.h
src/wl/sys/wlc_key.h
src/wl/sys/wl_linux.h
src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c
src/wl/sys/wlc_wowl.h
src/wl/sys/wl_iw.c
src/wl/sys/wlc_pub.h
src/wl/sys/wl_iw.h
src/wl/sys/wl_export.h
src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.h
src/wl/sys/wlc_ethereal.h
src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c
src/wl/sys/wlc_utils.h
src/wl/sys/wlc_types.h
src/common/
src/common/include/
src/common/include/proto/
src/common/include/proto/bcmeth.h
src/common/include/proto/ieee80211_radiotap.h
src/common/include/proto/ethernet.h
src/common/include/proto/802.1d.h
src/common/include/proto/bcmip.h
src/common/include/proto/bcmevent.h
src/common/include/proto/802.11.h
src/common/include/proto/wpa.h
./broadcom-wl-dkms.sh: line 22: 001-null-pointer-fix.patch: No such file or directory
sed: can't read dkms.conf.in: No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/share/licenses/broadcom-wl-dkms/LICENSE': File exists
install: cannot stat 'broadcom-wl-dkms.conf': No such file or directory
./broadcom-wl-dkms.sh: line 42: dkms: command not found
rmmod: ERROR: Module b43 is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module b43legacy is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module ssb is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module bcm43xx is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module brcm80211 is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module brcmfmac is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module brcmsmac is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module bcma is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module wl is not currently loaded
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.6.0-kali1-amd64
```

Sorry Im way too noob.Maybe I need to contact the author and ask him if he would upgrade this as of now?

**edit 3**

klanomath's script did compile succesfully but while trying to rmmod the conflictig modules and enabling wl at last the terminal returns:

```
root@kali:~# ./install-broadcom.sh
Makefile
lib/
lib/wlc_hybrid.o_shipped
lib/LICENSE.txt
src/
src/include/
src/include/typedefs.h
src/include/linuxver.h
src/include/bcmutils.h
src/include/siutils.h
src/include/packed_section_start.h
src/include/epivers.h
src/include/linux_osl.h
src/include/bcmendian.h
src/include/packed_section_end.h
src/include/pcicfg.h
src/include/bcmdefs.h
src/include/bcmcrypto/
src/include/bcmcrypto/tkhash.h
src/include/wlioctl.h
src/include/osl.h
src/shared/
src/shared/bcmwifi/
src/shared/bcmwifi/include/
src/shared/bcmwifi/include/bcmwifi_channels.h
src/shared/bcmwifi/include/bcmwifi_rates.h
src/shared/linux_osl.c
src/wl/
src/wl/sys/
src/wl/sys/wl_dbg.h
src/wl/sys/wlc_key.h
src/wl/sys/wl_linux.h
src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c
src/wl/sys/wlc_wowl.h
src/wl/sys/wl_iw.c
src/wl/sys/wlc_pub.h
src/wl/sys/wl_iw.h
src/wl/sys/wl_export.h
src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.h
src/wl/sys/wlc_ethereal.h
src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c
src/wl/sys/wlc_utils.h
src/wl/sys/wlc_types.h
src/common/
src/common/include/
src/common/include/proto/
src/common/include/proto/bcmeth.h
src/common/include/proto/ieee80211_radiotap.h
src/common/include/proto/ethernet.h
src/common/include/proto/802.1d.h
src/common/include/proto/bcmip.h
src/common/include/proto/bcmevent.h
src/common/include/proto/802.11.h
src/common/include/proto/wpa.h
broadcom-wl-dkms/
broadcom-wl-dkms/.SRCINFO
broadcom-wl-dkms/.gitignore
broadcom-wl-dkms/001-null-pointer-fix.patch
broadcom-wl-dkms/002-rdtscl.patch
broadcom-wl-dkms/003-linux47.patch
broadcom-wl-dkms/004-linux48.patch
broadcom-wl-dkms/005-debian-fix-kernel-warnings.patch
broadcom-wl-dkms/PKGBUILD
broadcom-wl-dkms/broadcom-wl-dkms.conf
broadcom-wl-dkms/broadcom-wl-dkms.install
broadcom-wl-dkms/dkms.conf.in
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/share/licenses/broadcom-wl-dkms/LICENSE': File exists

Creating symlink /var/lib/dkms/broadcom-wl/6.30.223.271/source ->
                 /usr/src/broadcom-wl-6.30.223.271

DKMS: add completed.

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...
applying patch 001-null-pointer-fix.patch...patching file src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 2165 (offset 8 lines).

applying patch 002-rdtscl.patch...patching file src/shared/linux_osl.c

applying patch 003-linux47.patch...patching file src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c

applying patch 004-linux48.patch...patching file src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c
Hunk #1 succeeded at 2386 (offset -2 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 2496 (offset -2 lines).
Hunk #3 succeeded at 2928 (offset 4 lines).

applying patch 005-debian-fix-kernel-warnings.patch...patching file src/wl/sys/wl_cfg80211_hybrid.c


Building module:
cleaning build area...
make -j4 KERNELRELEASE=4.6.0-kali1-amd64 -C /lib/modules/4.6.0-kali1-amd64/build M=/var/lib/dkms/broadcom-wl/6.30.223.271/build...
cleaning build area...

DKMS: build completed.

wl.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - Found /lib/modules/4.6.0-kali1-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/wl.ko
   - Storing in /var/lib/dkms/broadcom-wl/original_module/4.6.0-kali1-amd64/x86_64/
   - Archiving for uninstallation purposes
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.6.0-kali1-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/

depmod....

DKMS: install completed.
rmmod: ERROR: Module b43 is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module b43legacy is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module ssb is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module bcm43xx is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module brcm80211 is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module brcmfmac is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module brcmsmac is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module bcma is not currently loaded
rmmod: ERROR: Module wl is not currently loaded
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Exec format error
root@kali:~#
```

also the `dmesg` output returns:

```
12.767741] wl: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
```

somewhere in the middle. IS this the element creating the problem ?

and `modprobe --force wl` 's log under dmesg:

```
[   18.862399] usbcore: registered new interface driver rndis_host
[   18.878990] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): usb0: link is not ready
[   19.533537] fuse init (API version 7.24)
[  685.317127] wl: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
[  690.440257] wl: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
[  965.367764] wl: disagrees about version of symbol module_layout
[ 1244.818590] wl: module_layout: kernel tainted.
[ 1244.818593] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[ 1244.818597] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[ 1244.820857] wl: Unknown symbol __check_object_size (err 0)
[ 1244.820901] wl: Unknown symbol cfg80211_connect_bss (err 0)
[ 1244.820925] wl: Unknown symbol page_offset_base (err 0)
[ 1244.820964] wl: Unknown symbol vmemmap_base (err 0)
```

also

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /lib/modules/4.6.0-kali1-amd64/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/wl.ko: Invalid module format
```

Comment: in case you don't get a good answer in a day or two, please flag your question for mod attention so we can migrate it to the Unix/Linux SE

Comment: @klanomath yeah that one too. But still no success.

Comment: @klanomath [link] https://docs.broadcom.com/docs/12358410 is this the right  one? couldn't find one for bcm4360/wl

Comment: @klanomath Ive edited the question

Comment: Reminder for myself: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/broadcom-wl-dkms/

Comment: @klanomath yeah I downloaded the arch supports from the same exact location too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above all the fancy responses here (respectfully), the only working solution is to update the distro. That's all actually.

Although, the chances of people stumbling upon a problem alike this is very rare, this is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

The following method should work:

- Change to the root user in Kali.
- Remove all remnants of your previous attempts to install the Broadcom driver *wl*.
- Install dkms in Kali:

  ```
  apt-get update
  apt-get install dkms
  ```
- Download the Broadcom driver [manually](http://docs.broadcom.com/docs/12358410) to your Downloads folder
- Download the patch [manually](https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/snapshot/broadcom-wl-dkms.tar.gz) to your Downloads folder
- Create (`nano ~/install-broadcom.sh`, copy and paste the lines below, write to disk and quit with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>) and afterwards execute the script:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  # Installs the broadcom-wl kernel module with DKMS
  # Tested under Fedora 23, will likely work with other versions/distros
  # Author: Steven Mirabito <smirabito@csh.rit.edu>

  # Create a work directory
  mkdir -p /tmp/broadcom
  cd /tmp/broadcom

  # Download the module from Broadcom (http://www.broadcom.com/support/?gid=1) manually to ~/Downloads
  # https://docs.broadcom.com/docs/12358410

  # Download some support files from the Arch package manually ~/Downloads
  # https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/snapshot/broadcom-wl-dkms.tar.gz

  cp ~/Downloads/broadcom-wl-dkms.tar.gz /tmp/broadcom/
  cp ~/Downloads/hybrid-v35_64-nodebug-pcoem-6_30_223_271.tar.gz /tmp/broadcom/broadcom.tar.gz


  # Untar the archives
  tar -zxvf broadcom.tar.gz
  tar -zxvf broadcom-wl-dkms.tar.gz

  # Patch the module
  sed -i -e "/BRCM_WLAN_IFNAME/s:eth:wlan:" src/wl/sys/wl_linux.c

  # Add the module version number to the dkms config file
  sed -e "s/@PACKAGE_VERSION@/6.30.223.271/" broadcom-wl-dkms/dkms.conf.in > dkms.conf

  # Create the destination directory
  mkdir -p /usr/src/broadcom-wl-6.30.223.271

  # Move files into place
  cp -RL src lib Makefile dkms.conf /usr/src/broadcom-wl-6.30.223.271

  # Fix permissions and link the license in the appropriate place
  chmod a-x "/usr/src/broadcom-wl-6.30.223.271/lib/LICENSE.txt"
  mkdir -p "/usr/share/licenses/broadcom-wl-dkms"
  ln -rs "/usr/src/broadcom-wl-6.30.223.271/lib/LICENSE.txt" "/usr/share/licenses/broadcom-wl-dkms/LICENSE"

  # Install the modprobe config to blacklist the other Broadcom modules
  install -D -m 644 broadcom-wl-dkms/broadcom-wl-dkms.conf "/etc/modprobe.d/broadcom-wl-dkms.conf"

  # Install and build the module
  dkms add -m broadcom-wl -v 6.30.223.271
  cp -RL /tmp/broadcom/broadcom-wl-dkms /var/lib/dkms/broadcom-wl/6.30.223.271/source/patches
  dkms install -m broadcom-wl -v 6.30.223.271

  # Activate the module
  rmmod b43 b43legacy ssb bcm43xx brcm80211 brcmfmac brcmsmac bcma wl
  modprobe wl

  # Clean up
  cd ~
  rm -rf /tmp/broadcom
  ```

I don't have a WLAN chip in my VM. So I can't prove the commands `rmmod ...` and `modprobe wl`. At least I don't get an error executing the last command ;-).

Comment: how do i get rid of this?                                        
`modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Exec format error`

Comment: What does dmesg yield while booting? Maybe the dkms.conf isn't properly crafted for Debian's environment.

Comment: Ive edited the question under edit 3 + dmesg and the terminal output post script execution:

Comment: @Anon Have you also tried `modprobe --force wl`? The dmesg error you get is probably related to some Linux kernel headers. A similar problems can be found here: [Modprobe, Exec format error](https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/issues/84) - different driver though. You may remove all drivers and compile it manually like indicated in the thread...

Comment: modprobe --force's dmesg and insmod  also have been added under question details

Comment: maybe i need to patch the kernel like this guy did (its at the end of the forum)  (http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/invalid-module-format-both-broadcom-wireless-and-nvidia-gfx-858676/) but i dont know how could you please help me with this. My kali-linux kernel version is in the question. Also do I need to dist-upgrade my kali or something?